# Unstack a Dataframe in Pandas with certain order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, reshape

I have some given data `d`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict

table = OrderedDict((
    ("Item", ['Item0', 'Item0', 'Item1', 'Item1']),
    ('CType',['Gold', 'Bronze', 'Gold', 'Bronze']),
    ('USD',  [1, 2, 3, 4]),
    ('EU',   [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4])
))
d = pd.DataFrame(table)
```

Which I want to reshape. Not to this:

```
dU = d.set_index(['Item','CType']).unstack(['CType'])
dU
```

```
        USD             EU
CType   Bronze  Gold    Bronze  Gold
Item                
Item0   2       1       2.2     1.1
Item1   4       3       4.4     3.3
```

But to:

```
        Bronze          Gold
CType   EU      USD     EU      USD
Item                
Item0   2.2     2       1.1     1
Item1   4.4     4       3.3     3
```

How can I set the "order" of the Index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dV = dU.reorder_levels((1,0), axis = 1).sort_index(axis = 1)
```